# Invalid left-hand side in assignment : Uncaught ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("blue").text-color = "darkblue";
</script>
```

I saw this as a practicing section for JavaScript beginners. I am unable to find the error.

```
<div>
    <span class="blue">This text should be dark blue.</span><br>
</div>
```

What change must be done to rectify this error?

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns *HTMLCollection*. You have to specify index to get the element you want. To set the color of the text you have to set the `color` property on `style`:

Change `document.getElementsByClassName("blue").text-color = "darkblue";`

To

`document.getElementsByClassName("blue")[0].style.color = "darkblue";`

**Working Code Example:**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("blue")[0].style.color = "darkblue";
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="blue">This text should be dark blue.</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @danielcliff, place the script after HTML.